# Building options for input fields

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, form

In the `_form` partial I have a rather complicated logic which builds necessary options for input fields:

```
- input_html_params = dynamic_settings_select_options('#service-settings', settings_aps_instance_services_path(parent))

= simple_form_for [:aps, parent, resource] do |f|
  = f.input :service_status, :as => :readonly_label 
  = f.input :meta_service_meta_id, :collection => parent.meta_services, :value_method => :meta_id, :label_method => :name, :input_html => input_html_params
  = f.button :submit
```

The first problem which I see here is getting `input_html_params` to pass them into input of `meta_service_meta_id` because it already has a lot of parameters. Even this didn't help us to avoid long string to pass all parameters. What is best practice to avoid this complicity?

As you can see, extracting them to helper methods doesn't solve this problem, so I would like to hear something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a [Simple Form Custom Input](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs).

As I don't know Simple Form well enough, I don't know if you can access the routes from a custom input class.

If not, see the answers to these questions:

- [Accessing Rails RESTful routes in the model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447160/accessing-rails-restful-routes-in-the-model)

and

- [Rails, get resource path in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380703/rails-get-resource-path-in-model)